I can add .php to the end of my website link
I’m running a website using Nginx with PHP, and I’m trying to block manual access to URLs with the .php extension. My goal is to return a 404 error when users add .php to the URL, but allow clean URLs (without .php) to work properly. For example:
https://example.com/login.php → should return a 404.
https://example.com/login → should work and internally serve login.php.
However, with the configurations I’ve tried, either I end up with a redirect loop or get a 404 error, and the clean URLs are not working as expected.
server {
    `root /var/www/html/example;
    index index.php index.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # Block manual access to .php URLs and return 404
    location ~* \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    # Direct clean URLs to .php files (e.g., /login → login.php)
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$uri.php?$args;
    }

    # Process PHP files (internally)
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;`
}


I would recommend that you read up on the front controller pattern and then use a router to handle the URL's (which you set up in your application) instead. Then you can easily decide exactly what path you want. It's also how most frameworks and CMS's do it.

For a simple solution that may issue 403 instead of 404 (not sure). Remove the first location ~* \.php$ block which is your redirect loop, and add internal; to the location ~ \.php$ block which bans external access.

The following block is counterproductive as it overrides the location ~ \.php$ block and also causes a redirection loop.
# Block manual access to .php URLs and return 404
location ~* \.php$ {
    return 404;
}

The above block must be removed.

This simplest solution to prevent external access to URLs ending with .php is to mark the block which processes these requests with the internal directive.
For example:
# Process PHP files (internally)
location ~ \.php$ {
    internal;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

Nginx will respond with a 404 status instead.
